# Validate application/octet-stream MIME type for JPG with PaperClip Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, mime-types, paperclip-validation

My Rails 4.2.5 app is receiving JPG uploads from a mobile app. However, the MIME Type in the headers is:

```
application/octet-stream
```

PaperClip 4.3.2 returns the following error:

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 70221009989740.jpg (application/octet-stream from Headers, ...
```

I bypassed this issue using:

```
validate_media_type => false
```

and

```
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type
```

options.

However, this seems insecure. How can the media_type and file_type be correctly validated on MIME Type "application/octet-stream"?

Comment: maybe while sending data from your mobile application, you need to set correct headers for your data.

Comment: How exactly are you uploading these images? AJAX, form submission, etc.

Comment: I use the "Rho::AsyncHttp.upload_file" function from Rhomobile to send these pictures from the mobile app. The content_type is set to "application/octet-stream" there. I may have shot myself in the foot with this one.